# How to call methods on a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, variables

I saw the below syntax in a training video and I was wondering what this is called and which methods can we use on a variable?

```
 DECLARE @text VARCHAR(max);
 SET @text = REPLICATE(CAST('asdfasdf' as varchar(max)),8000);
 SET @text.write('zzzzzzzz',0,8);
 SELECT @text
```

the value stored in the variable is
'zzzzzzzzasdfasdf...'

Comment: It is documented in the `UPDATE` topic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#updating-lobs - though in the context of an `UPDATE` statement of course

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78876/write-clause-performance-optimization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update.write` syntax is not really a method. It is a TSQL syntax for updating large data types like nvarchar(max).

The official [UPDATE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) describes how to use .WRITE.

```
  SET  
        { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL }  
          | { udt_column_name.{ { property_name = expression  
                                | field_name = expression }  
                                | method_name ( argument [ ,...n ] )  
                              }  
          }  
          | column_name { .WRITE ( expression , @Offset , @Length ) }
```

> .WRITE (expression,@Offset,@Length) Specifies that a section of the
> value of column_name is to be modified. expression replaces @Length
> units starting from @Offset of column_name. Only columns of
> varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or varbinary(max) can be specified with
> this clause. column_name cannot be NULL and cannot be qualified with a
> table name or table alias.
>
> expression is the value that is copied to column_name. expression must
> evaluate to or be able to be implicitly cast to the column_name type.
> If expression is set to NULL, @Length is ignored, and the value in
> column_name is truncated at the specified @Offset.
>
> @Offset is the starting point in the value stored in column_name at
> which expression is written. @Offset is a zero-based ordinal byte
> position, is bigint, and cannot be a negative number. If @Offset is
> NULL, the update operation appends expression at the end of the
> existing column_name value and @Length is ignored. If @Offset is
> greater than the byte length of the column_name value, the Database
> Engine returns an error. If @Offset plus @Length exceeds the end of
> the underlying value in the column, the deletion occurs up to the last
> character of the value.
>
> @Length is the length of the section in the column, starting from
> @Offset, that is replaced by expression. @Length is bigint and cannot
> be a negative number. If @Length is NULL, the update operation removes
> all data from @Offset to the end of the column_name value.

See also [Updating Large Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#updating-lobs) and the [examples provided for updating large data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#updating-lobs).

Comment: `STUFF` will create a new object in memory and just overwrite the value stored currently (when used in SET). `.WRITE` modifies it in place, which is useful when you're working with MAX length data which can be (hundreds of) megabytes in size.

Comment: The BOL even says "To achieve the same functionality of .WRITE with other character or binary data types, use the STUFF"

Answer (score 2):

It's not a method, though it sure looks like it. Unlike for example [XML methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-ver16), which you can use in a SELECT, this is a mutator. It's available on (n)varchar and varbinary data types with `max` length  specified, and is used to modify the stored values efficiently.

There's not much information about them out there, I only found [this blog post](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/update-textntext-or-varcharmax-data-type-columns-in-sql-server/).